# Is it safe to multiply a float/double by 0.5 instead of divide by 2 in C# and C++?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, performance, optimization

Basically for things like this (not real code):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i)
{
     Vert v0 = mesh.polygons[i].edges[0].vert0;
     Vert v1 = mesh.polygons[i].edges[0].vert1;

     Vector3 center = (v0.pos + v1.pos) / 2;
}
```

`v0.pos` is of type `Vector3<float, float, float>`, but could be `Vector3<double, double, double>`.

Is it safe to just do?:

```
Vector3 center = (v0.pos + v1.pos) * 0.5;
```

This might seem like premature optimization but this has to be as fast as possible that will be called on billions of points (point clouds).

Comment: What happens when you measure the performance of both choices? You can't talk about optimisation at this level without *measuring* the result on your target platform.

Comment: Measure it either way.  But your compiler 'should' already revert to bit-shifting to divide by 2.

Comment: Agreed with Greg. Also, keep in mind that you should focus on correctness before speed. Much of the time, the compiler will optimize much of this for you (especially when you use literals).

Comment: Do you mean v0.pos is of type `Vector3<float, float, float>`, but could be `Vector3<double, double, double>`?  Your example looks like you are specifying constructor parameters, which wouldn't change the type.

Comment: @Chad: Not for floating point, I hope.

Comment: @Chad Not in this case. The bit-shifting case only works on integers.

Comment: @Chad this is a floating point representation, you can't simply bit shift.

Comment: @Greg, I didn't measure yet, but will do today to see if I get any difference. I wanted to add this optimization because one of my coworkers who is a very skilled graphics programmer told me divisions are slow as hell so use multiplication if you can.

Comment: There's no way to know this before profiling. This 'skilled' programmer should've told you to profile before making the decision. :)

Comment: Memory access is going to be the bottleneck there. On modern day hardware, mul and div FP ops are quite similar in performance. The optimisation was perhaps more useful 10 years ago.

Comment: Then, measure! I'm sure dividing by a constant is just as efficient as multiplying by a constant. But to answer the original question: yes, it is safe. Or wasn't that the real question?

Comment: Yes I was wondering if the result would be different because I read that you can't do this for any value, i.e. `x / 7`, vs `y = 1/7`, `x*y`, etc. Is this not true?

Comment: In this case it will be safe because both `2` and `0.5` are exactly representable in binary. But I won't speak for performance as the compiler may already be doing that for you.

Comment: @Mysticial We had a similar topic some time ago for C# and the compiler didn't do this optimization (replacing a div with a mul if constant exactly representable). Maybe c++ compilers are better here (someone check on intel?). Assuming a modern Intel CPU the win is about ~15 cycles iirc.

Comment: I just tested it. Yes VC++ does seem to replace `/2` with `*.5`.

Comment: @Mysticial Good to know. And to be clear in my above comment: With "the compiler" I meant the JIT (I usually equal the two for java/c# because no interesting optimization is done by their compilers, but it may be unclear in this context). So the answer should be: Check if your compiler/JIT is not already doing it before doing anything rash ;)

Comment: @GregHewgill, right you are, and that is why I shouldn't reply prior to my 3rd cup of coffee.

Comment: Since you mention C#, if you are after performance you should really be using pointers rather than array index when accessing your `mesh.polygons`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a C++ expert by any means, but in C#, doing this:

```
var a = new Func<float, float, double>((float f1, float f2) => (f1 + f2) * 0.5);
var b = new Func<float, float, double>((float f1, float f2) => (f1 + f2) / 2);
```

generates IL that in the former:

1. Loads the arguments
2. Adds them (producing a single)
3. Converts the result to a double
4. Loads the double argument (0.5)
5. Multiplies (producing a double)
6. Returns the result

and the latter

1. Loads the arguments
2. Adds them (producing a single)
3. Loads the constant integer (2)
4. Divides (producing a single, because single / integer produces a single)
5. Converts the result to a double
6. Returns the result

It strikes me that the former will likely have higher precision because the multiplication is performed on 2 doubles, resulting in double precision, whereas in the latter the division is performed on a single which is upcast to a double (but still only will have the precision of the single).

This bears me out:

```
Console.Out.WriteLine(((double)1) * ((double)1/3));
Console.Out.WriteLine((1) / ((float)3));
```

produces:

```
0.333333333333333
0.3333333
```

So, 'safe', maybe, if <del>losing precision</del> *gaining extra precision* is ok.

Comment: *"5. Converts the result to a double"*: Are those delegates `Func<float,float,double>` by any chance?

Comment: Yep, sorry, bad copy on my part...  Fixed.

Comment: True enough and good point, but it seems to me that the question is about whether changing the division to a multiplication could change the result (assuming the same input for both), in which case I don't see how this would be the case. i.e. casting (f1+f2) to double before dividing or 0.5 to float and the result should be identical

Comment: It does change the result- that's what I'm illustrating above.  I have two methods with the same signature that both calculate an average between two floats.  One uses (x+y)*0.5, and the other uses (x+y)/2, and they return numbers of different precision.  the values are equivalent at the shorter precision, yes, but precision may matter in his use case.

Comment: As I said, if you cast the values so that the division/multiplication is using the same precision input the output will be the same. Most of your post is about showing that this is not the case for your example, so I assume you misunderstood me?

Comment: I wrote my response before the edit to your comment, but yes, I misunderstood you.  Apologies.

Comment: Ah sorry, yes I thought the original may have been unclear and edited it a bit. Apologies on my part!

Comment: Down voted because you casted 3 to a float which caused it to lose precision instead of a double.